# Find all entry_ids without a certain value in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I'm struggling with finding rows that don't contain a certain pairing using MySQL.

I have a table with two columns, "entry_id" and "cat_id".  Each entry_id can be listed more than once, but will always have a different cat_id.  I need to find the entry_ids that have no associated cat_id of a certain value.  So for example, if there are any rows that have no cat_id = 1235, I need just the entry_id(s).

+----------+--------+
| entry_id | cat_id |
+----------+--------+
| 100001   | 1234   |
+----------+--------+
| 100001   | 1235   |
+----------+--------+
| 100001   | 1236   |
+----------+--------+
| 100002   | 1234   |
+----------+--------+
| 100002   | 1236   |
+----------+--------+
...

So in the above example table, if I was looking for the cat_id of 1235 as the "missing" pairing, a search would turn up entry_id 100002

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you familiar with `EXISTS`?

Comment: I wasn't but I am now familiar with EXISTS.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT entry_id 
  FROM tableA t1 
  WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * 
                    FROM tableA t2 
                    WHERE t2.entry_id = t1.entry_id AND
                    t2.cat_id = 1235)
```

Output:

```
entry_id
100002
```

Comment: That did the trick, thank you, I wasn't 100% clear on how to use EXISTS with a SELECT.

Comment: No worries. You can also use it to find all entries which DO have a certain cat_id by changing NOT EXISTS to EXISTS.